# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^kk!}{k^k}$ does not converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am doing an exercise where I have to consider the radius and interval of convergence of a series of functions. I found one endpoint to be $e/2$ and I now need to consider whether or not the following sum diverges.
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^kk!}{k^k}$$

---

I have found from calculators that it diverges but I do not know how to prove this.

Cauchy's ratiotest is inconclusive, as it gives the value 1.

Any help?

Comment: Use Strilings' approximation of $k!$

Comment: prove that $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{e^k k!}{k^k}=\infty$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that's not been covered so there must be another way?

Comment: Hey Dr. Graubner how would I calculate that limit? Should I substitute $e=(\frac{k+1}{k})^k$? I tried that but it only seems to make things messy. @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: i would compute $$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$$ for the sequence $$a_k=\frac{e^k k!}{k^k}$$

Comment: That fraction equals $e (\frac{k}{k+1}) ^k$, of which the limit as $k$ goes to infinity is equal to $1$, so I can't apply a ratio test there, can I? @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: can you post your steps please?

Comment: $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{e^{k+1}}{e^k}\frac{(k+1)!}{k!}\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}=e(k+1)\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}=e\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k}}=e(\frac{k}{k+1})$

Comment: @QuestionMaker, We can proceed from Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's comment by utilizing the inequality that $(1 + \frac{1}{k})^k < e$. This can be proved in various ways, for instance, you can show that $(1 + \frac{1}{k})^{k}$ strictly increases using [*Bernoulli's inequality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality), or you can apply the binomial theorem to expand $(1+\frac{1}{k})^k$ and compare the resulting sum with $e = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j!}$.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it. I used indeed Bernoulli to prove that the strictly increasing which lead to Dr. Graubner's fraction to be more or equal to 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you expand $e^k$ you will find a term $\cfrac {k^k}{k!}$ and all other terms are positive.

Answer (score 2):

Stirling's approximation tells us $n! = \sqrt{2 \pi n}\frac{n^n}{e^n} (1+ O(1/n))$.

Now, plug this into the summand and see what it behaves like.